# Why is my Ajax application not working in my localhost computer?

Tags: php, ajax, xampp, localhost

my XAMPP is activated but the Ajax scripts are not working. It should really work because I got it from a book and double checked the codes and the connections for the database but it didn't work.

Whats the problem anyhow?

The code is located on Chapter 5 http://www.myphpbook.com/download
I just started to programming so I dont have any idea how to make this work.

Comment: You're going to have to provide a lot more information than that.

Comment: Such as the exact code you're trying to use. And there's a good chance we might need more after that, but code's a great starting point.

Comment: "are not working" is no valid problem description. provide a lot more information about the whole environment, etc. otherwise it's like the story about this famous needle and the haystack.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have JavaScript code making a request from PHP code. Is the JavaScript making the request? You can use Firebug to set breakpoints and see network requests.

Is the PHP code that serves the request running?

Was everything going well before Chapter 5?